# Compiled LINQ Query returning Bool Value?

Tags: c#, linq

How to write a LINQ query to return `Bool` value?

My code thus far,

```
public class AddNewRow
    {
        public static Func<DatabaseDataContext, DateTime, int, Staff_Time_TBL>
            GetNewRowMissingData =
                     CompiledQuery.Compile((DatabaseDataContext db, DateTime dDate, int staffNo) =>
                     db.Staff_Time_TBLs.Any(a => a.Date_Data == dDate && a.Staff_No == staffNo));
    }
```

and tried this as well,

```
public class AddNewRow
    {
        public static Func<DatabaseDataContext, DateTime, int, Staff_Time_TBL>
            GetNewRowMissingData =
                     CompiledQuery.Compile((DatabaseDataContext db, DateTime dDate, int staffNo) =>
                     db.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(a => a.Date_Data == dDate && a.Staff_No == staffNo).Any());
    }
```

So if both criteria are met then return true.

Any of the other code I have tried will just clutter the post.

Research links,

- [Compiling query with IQueryable return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217954/compiling-query-with-iqueryablebool-return-value)
- [Linq query return true or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965423/linq-query-return-true-or-false)

Plus I have the book [Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework (Expert's Voice in .NET)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242337) which I am referencing from.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? The first LINQ query is "better"/more idiomatic,

Comment: @ChrisF, to make a compiled query return a bool value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your function definition:

```
public static Func<DatabaseDataContext, DateTime, int, Staff_Time_TBL>
```

According to the [MSDN page on compiled queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297(v=vs.100).aspx) this would take a `DateTime`, and `int` as input parameters and return a `Staff_Time_TBL` as the result.

The last type is the return type so you need to have a `bool` at the end:

```
public static Func<DatabaseDataContext, DateTime, int, bool>
```

Then in your query I'd use the `Any` that takes a predicate as it's more idiomatic to give the final result:

```
public class AddNewRow
{
    public static Func<DatabaseDataContext, DateTime, int, bool>
        GetNewRowMissingData =
                 CompiledQuery.Compile((DatabaseDataContext db, DateTime dDate, int staffNo) =>
                 db.Staff_Time_TBLs.Any(a => a.Date_Data == dDate && a.Staff_No == staffNo));
}
```

This should return you the answer you desire.

Comment: So I had to go through all of that to say that I was missing `bool` at the end. Thanks a heap for the answer, that is all was after. Up vote fro the effort and I will mark the answer solved.